# How do you pass multiple variables from functions to main in C?

Tags: c, return, argument-passing

How do I pass back a local variable from a function to `main`, if said function already has a return value? Sorry for the question, I'm trying to make it as objective as possible for everyone, not just my case.

Specifically: I have a function called `subtotal`. There are two counting variables. One of them  I returned with a `return`. The other I need to make available for use by my `main()` function.

edit: To clarify:

```
function something() {
   float counter = 0.0;
   int someOtherVar = 0;

   // the work

   return someOtherVar;
}
```

What I want to do is pass the `counter` float to `main`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass a pointer to the extra return value as a parameter to the function.

```
int foo(int *anotherOutParam)
{
    *anotherOutParam = 1;
    return 2;
}
```

And to call it:

```
int ret1, ret2;
ret1 = foo(&ret2);
//do something with ret2
```

Oftentimes, @Mat's suggestion of packing all the return values into a `struct` is preferable.

Comment: Thanks, got it, I added some clarification to my question though.

Comment: The code in my answer essentially implements what you describe in your clarification. Replace `int *anotherOutParam` with `float *counter` and you are done.

Comment: Problem is I defined it as `float *count;` which is fine, but then I try to do `count += anotherVar;` and it gives me this error: `invalid operands to binary + (have 'float *' and 'double')`.

Comment: Very hard to debug this from here. Is count a local variable or is it the pointer parameter passed to the function? If the former then that doesn't make much sense. If the latter then you increment by writing `*count += anotherVar`.

Comment: It is a local variable. Okay that worked, but now how can I reference it and change it's value in other functions and in main? I need to send that local variable to main and other functions as well

Comment: You seem to be asking the original question again. I guess we are not really connecting here. What don't you get about my answer?

Comment: Haha. You assign ret1 to foo with a parameter of ret2. All I need to actually do is be able to make use a variable in a function, that's all. I don't need to send anything to that function to modify it. I just need to use it. So I want to send it from the function -> main, not main -> send value to function -> return value. Does that make any sense? I can't add another parameter to the function for this variable because this function is used in other parts of the program and I'd just have to put random gibberish into that one extra parameter I add, just to send this variable to main somehow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9610/discussion-between-david-heffernan-and-eveo)

Answer (score 11):

Put all your return values in a `struct`, and return that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myret {
    int total;
    int count;
};

struct myret foo(void)
{
    struct myret r;
    r.total = 42;
    r.count = 2;
    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct myret r = foo();
    printf("%d %d\n", r.total, r.count);
    return 0;
}
```

Or use pointers for the "other" return values.

```
int foo(int *other)
{
   if (other)
     *other=42;
   return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a = 0;
   int b = foo(&a);
   ...
}
```

You can also combine both by passing a pointer to a struct to your function, and have your function fill that in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myret {
    int total;
    int count;
};

int foo(struct myret *r)
{
    if (r) {
        r->total = 42;
        r->count = 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct myret r;
    int rc = foo(&r);
    if (rc == 0) {
        printf("%d %d\n", r.total, r.count);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: +1: Whilst "returning" individual parameters via the argument list works, encapsulating it like the first example is much cleaner, and so should normally be preferred.

Comment: +1 I agree, returning an encapsulated struct is the way to go

Comment: Only do this if all the elements of the struct are logically related to each other (IOW, they're attributes of a larger, composite type); don't create an aggregate type *for the sole purpose* of returning multiple *unrelated* items from a function.

Comment: @JohnBode: a single function probably shouldn't be 'calculating' completely unrelated things.

Comment: Haven't learned structs yet, therefore I am not allowed to use structs.

Comment: Well, the second version doesn't require structs, but it does require pointers. (And it isn't really the best IMO, except sometime for "optional" "out parameters".)

Comment: @Mat: agreed, but *shouldn't* doesn't always mean *doesn't*.